# How to remove option bar from ggplotly plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, shinydashboard

I have a plot that I am rendering in `shiny` using `plotly` and `ggplot2`. However, I do not want the option bar that appears on hover to appear. Is there a way to use `ggplotly(p)` and remove the option bar?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is a great answer on [community plotly](http://community.plot.ly/t/disable-interactions-in-plotly-for-r-and-ggplot2/1361/4) the short version:

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
```

Using `ggplotly`:

```
p <- ggplot(d, aes(carat, price)) + geom_point()
ggplotly(p) %>% config(displayModeBar = FALSE)
```

If you are not using `ggplotly` you can do:

```
plot_ly(d, x = carat, y = price, text = paste("Clarity: ", clarity),
mode = "markers", color = carat, size = carat) %>% config(displayModeBar = FALSE)
```

Comment: is there any way of doing this more permanently? for instance if I save this as a webpage, the toolbar is back

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer everytime I come back for it (which is a lot)

Comment: @BastiaanQuast did you solve the issue of toolbar appearing on webpage?